# .htaccess rule for domain.com to www.domain.com/index.php OR domain.com/index.php to www.domain.com/index.php

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering how can I use `.htaccess` rules to point my domain to index.php
What I actually need it to do:

1. When a user enters `domain.com` it takes him to `www.domain.com/index.php`

AND

1. When a user enters `domain.com/index.php` it takes him to `www.domain.com/index.php`
   **Or** When a user enters `domain.com/file.php` it takes him to `www.domain.com/file.php`

I have got some rules by searching here on stackoverflow, but these were incomplete and no one was able to perform both functions.

One rule was this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$

RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

When a user enters domain.com it takes him to www.domain.com/index.php but it is not helping in redirecting user who enters domain.com/index.php to www.domain.com/index.php.. Or let's say any thing like domain.com/file.php to www.domain.com/file.php

Any one please help in this matter. I'm sure many users would like to know this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what **does** happen when you type `domain.com/index.php`?

Comment: It remains same domain.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my .htaccess file I've got

```
##
#  Rewrite http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com (for XYZ licence)
##

Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This works, but this method creates a problem when you have sub-domains. I have tried this and all of my subdomains started pointing like
sub.domain.com to www.domain.com/sub

Comment: You will need different .htaccess files in each of your subdomain roots and edit the `%{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com` as appropriate

Comment: Yeah ChrisW, it's working! Sorry before I was using another code little bit like yours. But now after inserting this rule, now every thing is working perfectly. :) Thank you!

Comment: You can check it now on hostug.com
And there was no need to add saperate rule for all domains after this rule on domain.com

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine   on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^file.php /file.php [L]
```

Comment: He wants the rule for **any** file, not just literally `domain.com/file.php` which this will do